# Is there a way to tell that our bitcoin is safe after we put it in a hardware wallet for cold storage after 3 or 5 years?

Tags: security, coldstorage, hardware-wallet

If I consolidated 1 bitcoin into an address using a hardware wallet, and put it in cold storage. Can I know after 3 to 5 years that the bitcoin is safe?

So far the research I have is: can I go to https://www.blockchain.com/btc/blocks and search for that address, and see that it was still used once (for the time I put the bitcoin in), and therefore know that the bitcoin is safe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use, for example, two or three different [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) to check the balance for your Bitcoin address(es).

Or you can set up a watch-only wallet on any PC or phone - import the Bitcoin-addresses but *not the private keys* and the wallet cannot spend the money, only monitor. The money will be shown by the wallet as "watch-only" or "non-spendable" (depending on the wallet). It will show you any transactions involving money at that bitcoin-address.